The commit-received hook is not displaying the list of committed files
"We have configured a Git server with Gerrit, and the Gerrit version is 2.16.28.The gerrit installed in linux server.Currently, we are committing projects from Eclipse using Windows OS. Now, the requirement is to display all the committed files from the commit-received hook. I have placed the commit-received hook under the .git/hooks location, and it works fine when I try to display some text at the time of the commit operation. However, when I attempt to display the list of committed files, it is not working. See the script below,
commit-received
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "pre receive" # this printing
while read oldrev newrev refname; do #from here it is not working
        # Get the list of committed files
        committed_files=$(git diff --name-only $oldrev $newrev)
    # Print the list of committed files
        echo "Committed files:"
        echo "$committed_files"
done

I am expecting to list out the current commit files.

What is commit-received hook? I don't see it in the docs.

it is a Gerrit hook not git hook. please refer this https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/hooks/+/HEAD/src/main/resources/Documentation/hooks.md#commit_received

I see, thanks! The hook seems to receive a lot of command line parameters: commit-received --project <project name> --refname <refname> --uploader <uploader> --uploader-username <username> --oldrev <sha1> --newrev <sha1> --cmdref <refname> . I think you should parse that parameters. read oldrev newrev refname shouldn't work; it works in pre-receive hook but not (I suppose) in Gerrit hooks.
